# How To Get Previous Data-Color Attribute?

Tags: javascript, attributes

The question is:

Write code in YOUR CODE HERE that logs the current and previous values of the data-color attribute on the #cro-headline element each time that the attribute changes. Your log statement should look something like this:
`console.log('Current color: ' + currentColor + ' | Previous Color: ' + previousColor);`

My answer so far:

```
var oldFunction = window.changeHeadlineColor;
window.changeHeadlineColor = function(croHeadline) {
  oldFunction(croHeadline);
  var currentElement = document.querySelector('#cro-headline');
  var currentColor = currentElement.dataset.color;
  var previousElement = currentElement.previousElementSibling;
  var previousColor = previousElement.dataset.color;
  console.log('Current color: ' + currentColor + ' | Previous Color: ' + previousColor);
}
```

I'm just not entirely sure how to log the previous value of the data-color attribute. Any help would be greatly appreciated!

HTML:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <style>
        [data-color="red"] { color: red; }
        [data-color="blue"] { color: blue; }
        [data-color="green"] { color: green; }
        [data-color="orange"] { color: orange; }
        [data-color="purple"] { color: purple; }
    </style>
    <script>
        window.myHandler = function () {
            console.log('Click!');
        };

        window.getRandomNumber = function (max) {
            return Math.floor(Math.random() * max)
        }

        var colors = ['red', 'blue', 'green', 'orange', 'purple'];
        window.changeHeadlineColor = function (croHeadline) {
            var random = getRandomNumber(5000);
            var randomString = random.toString();
            setTimeout(() => {
                var colorKey = (randomString.length < 4) ? 0 : parseInt(randomString.charAt(0));
                croHeadline.setAttribute('data-color', colors[colorKey]);
                changeHeadlineColor(croHeadline);
            }, random);
        };
    </script>
    <script>
        ////////////////////
        /* YOUR CODE HERE */
        ////////////////////
    </script>
</head>

<body>
    <div id="myDiv">OMG Click me!</div>
    <script>
        document.querySelector('#myDiv').addEventListener('click', myHandler);

        setTimeout(() => {
            myDiv.insertAdjacentHTML('beforebegin', '<h1 id="cro-headline" data-color="red">Cro Metrics</h1>');
            var croHeadline = document.querySelector('#cro-headline');
            changeHeadlineColor(croHeadline);
        }, getRandomNumber(5000));
    </script>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: create an array to hold the values of each change starting with your default, then push the values into the array each time you change the color, then use the index  - 1 to find the previous

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've added just a `previousColor = currentColor`.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <style>
    [data-color="red"] {
      color: red;
    }
    
    [data-color="blue"] {
      color: blue;
    }
    
    [data-color="green"] {
      color: green;
    }
    
    [data-color="orange"] {
      color: orange;
    }
    
    [data-color="purple"] {
      color: purple;
    }
  </style>
  <script>
    window.myHandler = function() {
      console.log('Click!');
    };

    window.getRandomNumber = function(max) {
      return Math.floor(Math.random() * max)
    }

    var colors = ['red', 'blue', 'green', 'orange', 'purple'];
    window.changeHeadlineColor = function(croHeadline) {
      var random = getRandomNumber(5000);
      var randomString = random.toString();
      setTimeout(() => {
        var colorKey = (randomString.length < 4) ? 0 : parseInt(randomString.charAt(0));
        croHeadline.setAttribute('data-color', colors[colorKey]);
        changeHeadlineColor(croHeadline);
      }, random);
    };
  </script>
  <script>
    var previousColor;
    var oldFunction = window.changeHeadlineColor;
    
    window.changeHeadlineColor = function(croHeadline) {
      oldFunction(croHeadline);
      var currentElement = document.querySelector('#cro-headline');
      var currentColor = currentElement.dataset.color;
      console.log('Current color: ' + currentColor + ' | Previous Color: ' + previousColor);
      previousColor = currentColor;
    }
  </script>
</head>

<body>
  <div id="myDiv">OMG Click me!</div>
  <script>
    document.querySelector('#myDiv').addEventListener('click', myHandler);

    setTimeout(() => {
      myDiv.insertAdjacentHTML('beforebegin', '<h1 id="cro-headline" data-color="red">Cro Metrics</h1>');
      var croHeadline = document.querySelector('#cro-headline');
      changeHeadlineColor(croHeadline);
    }, getRandomNumber(1000));
  </script>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: Wow! I didn’t even consider that. Thank you!